# The sum of moment generating functions

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X, Y$ be independent r.v with moment generating functions $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$ respectively. Is there a function of $X$ and $Y, Z$, with moment generating function $$\frac{M_x(t) + M_y(t)}2$$

Answer (score 9):

Let $Z$ be independent of $X$ and $Y$ such that $P(Z=1)=P(Z=0)=\tfrac12$ and put $U=XZ+Y(1-Z)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
M_U(t)&=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{tU}]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{tX}\mathbf{1}_{Z=1}]+\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{t Y}\mathbf{1}_{Z=0}]\\
&=\tfrac12M_X(t)+\tfrac12 M_Y(t).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That would work ;)! Nice answer.