# Would these two give the same moment generating function?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Whilst reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015164/the-sum-of-moment-generating-functions) by Stefan. I am not entirely convinced why this equality holds:

$$\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{tU}]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{tX}\mathbf{1}_{Z=1}]+\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{t Y}\mathbf{1}_{Z=0}]$$

My confusion is, since $U=XZ+Y(1-Z)$, would we not have $E[e^{tU}]=E[e^{tXZ}]E[e^{tY(1-Z)}]$ instead?

However, if I robustly define $Z$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Z=X)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(Z=Y)=\frac{1}{2},$ wouldn't we achieve the same aim? That is $M_Z(t)=\frac{1}{2}(M_y(t)+M_Y(t)).$

Presumably my answer is not correct since I have not seen anyone commenting this, hence my question is why is my answer not correct? Why did Stefan introduce a brand new random variable (Z)?

Comment: Well, the first identity would still be true. But in the next step, you need to apply independence to get $\mathbb{E} e^{tX}1_{Z=1}=\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E} e^{tX}$ and thus, the final result.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Sorry yes I was more struggled with the second equality, I shall update what I was confused about.

Comment: Well, $ZX$ and $(1-Z)Y$ are, in general, not independent.

Comment: In fact, your argument shows that this can only be true if $\frac{1}{2}(M_X(t)+M_Y(t))=M_X(t)M_Y(t)$

Comment: @WoolierThanThou That makes sense! However, I am not understanding why by independence that the first inequality stated in my main body text hold? Would you mind if you could please elaborate in more detail?

Comment: The equality $f(U)=1_{Z=1} f(X)+1_{Z=0}f(Y)$ always holds for any function $f$ as a statement about maps. No independence or anything is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $Z$ such that $P(Z=X)=P(Z=Y)=\frac12$, you can get this far:
$$
\begin{aligned}
M_Z(t)=E(e^{tZ})&=E(e^{tZ}I_{(Z=X)}+e^{tZ}I_{(Z=Y)})\\&=E(e^{tZ}I_{(Z=X)}) + E(e^{tZ}I_{(Z=Y)})\\&=E(e^{tX}I_{(Z=X)})+E(e^{tY}I_{(Z=Y)})
\end{aligned}
$$
But from this point you cannot deduce
$$
E(e^{tX}I_{(Z=X)}) = E(e^{tX})P(Z=X)\tag{*}
$$
without an additional assumption. For example, you could conclude (*) if you knew that $X$ was independent of the event $\{Z=X\}$. (This would be true in the example given by Stefan, but notice that your $Z$ is his $U$.)